# R error incorrect number of subscripts on matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I am a beginner in R. I have two matrices with the same number of rows (let's say 10), and many columns. I want to do a linear regression, using glm, between eacg row of matrixA and the corresponding row of matrixB. I want to print the residuals in a new matrix, which will have the same number of rows as the original matrices:

```
matrixA <- read.table("fileA.txt", header=TRUE, row.names=1)
matrixB <- read.table("fileB.txt", header=TRUE, row.names=1)

for(i in 1:10) {
    response = as.matrix(matrixA)[i,]
    predictor = as.matrix(matrixB)[i,]
    fit <- glm(response ~ predictor)
    residuals[i,] <- fit$residuals
}
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
Error in residuals[1, ] <- fit$residuals : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

I looked up this error a bit, and thought that maybe it did not recognize fit$residuals as a vector, so I tried to specify it (as.vector(fit$residuals)), but that did not fix it.

Any idea on how I can fix this? Thank you!

Format of the matrices (both have the same format)

```
    a   b   c   d   f
A   1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0
B       …
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
```

Comment: Can I ask why my question is being downvoted?

Comment: Where does `residuals` come from? Do you really want it to be 2 Dimensional?

Comment: You can, but only the downvoter can answer. However, I can tell you I (and others) would be more willing to help if you provided data also. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your question. Do you mean "residuals[i,] <- ..."? I am just naming the new matrix "residuals" because it will contain residuals values...

Comment: I posted the format of my data. Sorry I just didn't see how this would help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to preallocate your output vector. However, it's easier/cleaner to use `mapply`. If you pass it two vectors (including lists) it iterates simultaneously over both and applies the function to the paired elements. Thus we only need to split the matrices into lists.

```
A <- matrix(1:9, 3)
B <- A * 3 + 2 + 1/A

t(mapply(function(a, b) {
  fit <- lm(b ~ a)
  residuals(fit)
}, split(A, letters[1:3]), split(B, letters[1:3])))
#           1           2          3
#a 0.10714286 -0.21428571 0.10714286
#b 0.03750000 -0.07500000 0.03750000
#c 0.01851852 -0.03703704 0.01851852

residuals(lm(B[1,] ~ A[1,]))
#        1          2          3 
#0.1071429 -0.2142857  0.1071429
```

Here is a `for` loop that does the same:

```
result <- matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(A), ncol = ncol(A))
for (i in seq_len(nrow(A))) {
  result[i,] <- residuals(lm(B[i,] ~ A[i,]))
}
#           [,1]        [,2]       [,3]
#[1,] 0.10714286 -0.21428571 0.10714286
#[2,] 0.03750000 -0.07500000 0.03750000
#[3,] 0.01851852 -0.03703704 0.01851852
```